# How can I add Auto-Complete feature in BotframeWork(Channel- Teams)?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Hi I am new to Botframework and exploring the possible features i can add in my bot. I making bot for MS-Teams and would like to know if we can add autocomplete feature in code.

I tried to find a way to track the typing event but no luck. Is there any event tracking in botframework as i can only see some limited functionality.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, auto-complete isn't a currently supported feature in any channel. There's been some chatter on having it for webchat [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/476), but it's not an official feature.

That being said, MS Teams has a feature for bots called 'Bot Menu':

[image: example menu being displayed on Teams channel]

According to their documentation, in order to use it, you only have to update your app manifest bot section:

```
{
  ⋮
  "bots":[
    {
      "botId":"[Microsoft App ID for your bot]",
      "scopes": [
        "personal",
        "team"
      ],
      "commandLists":[
        {
          "scopes":[
            "team",
            "personal"
          ],
          "commands":[
            {
              "title":"Help",
              "description":"Displays this help message"
            },
            {
              "title":"Search Flights",
              "description":"Search flights from Seattle to Phoenix May 2-5 departing after 3pm"
            },
            {
              "title":"Search Hotels",
              "description":"Search hotels in Portland tonight"
            },
            {
              "title":"Best Time to Fly",
              "description":"Best time to fly to London for a 5 day trip this summer"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Here's the MS Teams documetation on the feature: [Bot Menus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-menus)